# How can I suppress the "Welcome to OpenOffice.org" dialog on startup

Tags: macos, mac, openoffice

Is there a way to start OpenOffice.org without the "Welcome to OpenOffice.org "create a new document" dialog appearing every time?

I just wanna start it empty then do either File->Recent Documents or File->New without the annoying dialog box.

OO.o 3.2.0 on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

UPDATE: I mean this screen

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old reference: [Getting rid of the OpenOffice splash screen](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/29121).
<sup>some things may have changed a bit.</sup>

You can also do `ooffice --nologo` -- or, alias that.

---

Update: There is this discussion to [Disable welcome screen](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=10753),
and a few people there refer to [OpenOffice.org Aqua Rocks](http://stuporglue.org/openoffice.org-aqua-launchers.php).
Would that work for you?

Comment: This does suppress the splash screen, but that's not what I was after, its the next screen from that one.  I'll add a screenshot in a moment.

Comment: Those launchers in the "Aqua Rocks" work great for everything except Writer.  I'll have a mess about with it and see if I can get it going, thanks

Comment: Via your links I found a better solution (see my answer) but I'll keep yours as the accepted answer, since it was your help that got me there!

Answer (score 0):

Found an OpenOffice extension that disables this "StartCenter"

[Disable Start Module Extension](http://www.openoffice.org/nonav/issues/showattachment.cgi/58887/DisableStartModule.oxt)